# Add a 'global' UIView to an App with StoryBoard

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, storyboard

Is there a way to create a global UIView as background with the use of a StoryBoard?
I am updating my App, and making iOS 5 as the minimum so I can use ARC and also StoryBoards.

However, in my App I used a MainView.xib which I loaded as my rootviewcontroller, and any subsequent view was transparent so the background (and a button/copyright notice) were always visible.

I don't seem to be able to figure out how to do this. I can add the Subview to the rootview controller in the AppDelegate, but as soon as I seque to the next view it is gone.

Any suggestions how this can be done?

Comment: A segue is to a view controller rather than a view.  This matters because controllers assume they "own" the screen (or segment of it) that they work with and have no concept of preserving a previous display while presenting their views.

Comment: Thanks, yes. I think I found a way, more or less as I did before, by putting in at index 0 at the rootview controller. Will test this now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you can do this by adding an image view as a subview of the window itself, and making the backgrounds of all the view controllers clear.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    UIImageView *iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.window.frame];
    iv.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"BlueGreenGradient.tiff"];
    [self.window addSubview:iv];
    return YES;
}
```